# Shifting datetime index in selected rows of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains half hourly data. I want to shift a small range of datetime indices by 1 hour:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['datetime'] = pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2019-01-01', freq='30T')
df = df.set_index('datetime')

print(df.index)

# shift 1 hour forward for custom date range
date1 = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
date2 = '2016-03-02 23:49:50'
df[(df.index>=date1) & (df.index<=date2)].index += pd.Timedelta('1H')
#df.index = df[(df.index>=date1) & (df.index<=date2)].index.shift(periods=1,freq='H')

print(df.index)
```

I tried some different strategies (which don't work) but I want to know if there is a more compact way to do this. Note that this MWE has `freq=30T` but my actual data has `freq=None`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `df[mask]` generally produces a weakly linked copy of the original DataFrame containing only the filtered values. Meaning the expression `df[mask].index` creates a copy, `+= pd.Timedelta('1H')` updates the index of that copy and then throws the new DataFrame away since there is no variable reference.

One approach here would be to use [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.values.html) to update the underlying values (since the "Index does not support mutable operations"):

```
# shift 1 hour forward for custom date range
date1 = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
date2 = '2016-03-02 23:49:50'
df.index.values[(date1 <= df.index) & (df.index <= date2)] += pd.Timedelta('1H')
```

`df`:

```
                         0
datetime                  
2016-01-01 01:00:00      0  # Now starts at 01:00:00
2016-01-01 01:30:00      1
2016-01-01 02:00:00      2
2016-01-01 02:30:00      3
2016-01-01 03:00:00      4
```

---

In terms of a more concise method there aren't really any options when working with the index.

[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) works but is not necessarily more concise:

```
date1 = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
date2 = '2016-03-02 23:49:50'
df.index = np.where((date1 <= df.index) & (df.index <= date2),
                    df.index + pd.Timedelta('1H'),
                    df.index)
df.index.name = 'datetime'  # add index name back if needed
```

Converting [`to_series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_series.html) then using [`between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) is also an option, but requires making a complete copy of the index which is likely unnecessary:

```
date1 = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
date2 = '2016-03-02 23:49:50'
df.index.values[
    df.index.to_series().between(date1, date2)
] += pd.Timedelta('1H')
```

[`Index.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.shift.html) would also work if using the mask on both sides of the equation, but this requires masking the index twice:

```
date1 = '2016-01-01 00:00:00'
date2 = '2016-03-02 23:49:50'
m = (date1 <= df.index) & (df.index <= date2)
df.index.values[m] = df.index[m].shift(freq='1H')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [`pd.index.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.shift.html)

From the Pandas documentation:

> Notes
>
> This method is only implemented for datetime-like index classes, i.e.,
> DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex and TimedeltaIndex.